# Retrieving accidentally removed project folder in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I didn't know what I did in `eclipse`. I think I accidentally pressed Ctrl+z which somehow deleted a whole project folder from the explorer in the left hand. I opened the workspace directory and did NOT find the folder! It seems that eclipse deleted it.

How can I restore my work?
Is there anyway to get the work back ?

I mainly concern about the `.java` files. raw and drawable files are not a problem.

**In case this might help:** using eclipse, I run the project app in my HTC Magic (rooted with android 2.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's been deleted you can recover it - random link: http://lifehacker.com/393084/how-to-recover-deleted-files-with-free-software

Comment: Thanks a lot. I recover MOST of the files using [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva/download).

Comment: I really didn't think about `recovering tools`. May be because I got shocked after losing my whole project ;)

Answer (score 8):

- Right click on project.
- Select **Restore from Local history** option.
- In **Restore from Local history** window you can select the files you want to recover.

  Hoping this can restore your files or folder deleted from eclipse.

Comment: I didn't have the project folder. How come I can right-click on it ??

Answer (score 1):

This is what version control systems are born for.  Install Subversion or Mercurial or Git; check in early and often.  It's even helpful for local development when you're on your own - as you are finding out.

IntelliJ maintains a local history that allows you to revert to any earlier version.  Does Eclipse have such a thing?  I don't remember - it's been too long since I switched.

Comment: Is this an answer ?!! There is something called comment

Answer (score 0):

If it is gone from the actual folder it can either be moved (not very likely) or deleted. Use an undelete program to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

ok if it's not too late and you havent yet closed eclipse, on the top menu go to

edit -> undo (/Undo Delete Resource?)....

and if you only deleted it from  package explorer, import the folder again...I've been there and it totally SUCKS to lose all your work so hope you get it back...

Answer (score 0):

go straight into your /workspace now!
look for it in your computer directory under the eclipse folder
or go to
file> import> existing project into workspace> (check: select archive file) and click browse it should still be there.
i found mine in there and backed it up. so happy :D